# Compare two numeric custom fields

Tags: query, advanced-custom-fields

I use Advanced Custom Fields and have a custompost-type "matches". This post-type contains two fields "goals-made" and "goals-against".

I want to query wordpress to show only the matches that were won. So where "goals made" > "goals-against".

Can anyone help me get started on this one. The goal is to have a statistics page in the end.

Thx a lot for helping me out

Comment: I think that only chance is retrieving the posts that have both the meta fields and then looping trought them and do the comparison. Can be low performant but I don't see any other solution. If someone gives a better one, will get my +1 for sure.

Answer (score 4):

If I was in your situation, I'd used a different approach.

Simply add an hidden meta field automatically when goals_made is updated.

E.g.

```
add_action('updated_postmeta', 'update_goal_made', 20, 4);

function update_goal_made( $meta_id, $object_id, $meta_key, $_meta_value ) {
  if ( $meta_key != 'goals-made') return; // run only when update meta 'goals-made'
  // get the goals-against for post
  $against = get_post_meta($object_id, 'goals-against', true) ? : 1;
  // if 'goals-made' > 'goals-against' create/update a field '_goals-won' setted to 1
  if ( intval($_meta_value) > intval($against) ) {
    update_post_meta($object_id, '_goals-won', '1');
  } else {
    // if not delete '_goals-won' post meta (if exists)
    delete_post_meta($object_id, '_goals-won');
  }
}
```

Now to retrieve the posts where `_goals-won` exists, simply run a meta query:

```
$args = (
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'meta_query' => array( array('meta_key'=>'_goals-won') )
);
$won_posts = get_posts($args);
```

---

### EDIT

After some works on [**GhostToast answer**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/113608/compare-two-numeric-custom-fields/113647#113647) I can give you also the right SQL query to get the same result.

```
global $wpdb;
$won_posts = $wpdb->get_results( "
    SELECT $wpdb->posts.* 
        FROM $wpdb->posts
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta AS mt1 ON ( $wpdb->posts.ID = mt1.post_id )
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta AS mt2 ON ( $wpdb->posts.ID = mt2.post_id )
    WHERE mt1.meta_key = 'goals-made' 
        AND ( 
            mt2.meta_key = 'goals-against'
            AND CAST( mt1.meta_value AS UNSIGNED ) > CAST( mt2.meta_value AS UNSIGNED )
        )
    GROUP BY $wpdb->posts.ID
" );
```

---

***Side note:***

<del>If someone write the SQL statement that handle your request,</del> sure that SQL statement will be less performant then the simplest meta query like the first posted.

Comment: This is certainly the "least work" approach, and I support that. But also very curious to see a custom sql statement which handles this. I started to write one but moved on ;)

Comment: If someone writes that sql statement will get my +1 and my boundless admiration ;) @GhostToast

Comment: +1 for the query. Just two questions: (1) Why do you have to join the table twice instead of simply using the first one? Or couldn't you simply use `$wpdb->postmeta` instead of the alias? (2) Why do you use `UNSIGNED` instead of `INT`?

Comment: @kaiser *(1)* Without the 2nd `JOIN` the query doesn't work (because the `WHERE` clause look for an unknown table, once the meta table is treated as 2 different tables to make query works). Of course I can join using `$wpdb->postmeta`, reason for another alias is just *aestetic* :) *(2)* For some reason (I'm *not* an SQL expert) `INT` doesn't work. Looking in [official MySQL 5.1 docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) it **doesn't** figure among supported types for `CAST`.

Comment: Still not sure why we have to do the `JOIN` twice and treat it as two different tables. Btw, I _think_ you could limit the `SELECT` to `ID, post_id, meta_key, meta_value` - but not sure about that.

Comment: @kaiser I've tried to use one join and get SQL error: the part `mt2.meta_key = 'goals-against'` throw `UNKNOWN COLUMN mt2.meta_key` or (`UNKNOWN COLUMN wp_postmeta.meta_key` if no alias).

Comment: @kaiser how can I +1 an edit? :) Damn GhostToast! (I'm joking)

Answer (score 4):

I think something like this, but not tested, and my SQL-foo is rather weak:

```
    $test = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare(
    "
    SELECT DISTINCT    $wpdb->posts.*
    FROM               $wpdb->posts
    INNER JOIN         $wpdb->postmeta AS mt1 ON (
         wp_posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id
    )
    WHERE              $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'goals-made'
    AND(               mt1.meta_key = 'goals-against'
        AND            CAST($wpdb->postmeta.meta_value AS INT) > CAST(mt1.meta_value AS INT)
    )

    "
));
```

This should return a list of post_ids that you can then process. But then again, it might just fail miserably.

Comment: This do not compare for >. To retrieve post that have both fileds, and the looping and do the compare, it's possible to use the standard  meta_query, with relation 'AND': `'meta_query' => array('relation'=>'AND', array('key' => 'goals-made'), array('key' => 'goals-against') )`

Comment: What you describe does not inherently compare either, however. If you perform a combined meta_query, it is probably simpler to do the comparison afterwards. While I am not confident in the exact structure of my query, it should be comparing those two values as cast integers.

Comment: Ah, ok, my bad, I don't read your sql well. (I miss the '>' between the 2 cast). Ave you tested? I'm going to.

Comment: 1 less important problem: $wpdb->prepare do nothing ant throw a notice when there is nothing to prepare (no 2n argument). 2 more important problem: `WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INT) > CAST(mt1.meta_value AS INT) )' at line 8]` No +1 this time ;)

Comment: Shrug. A stab in the dark. Perhaps INT is not supported on your server? :)

Comment: Men, you got +1 this time! :) There was only few MySQL syntax errors on your query, but it's the right direction! The working and tested version: `$wpdb->get_col("SELECT DISTINCT $wpdb->posts.ID FROM $wpdb->posts INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta AS mt1 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id ) INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta AS mt2 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt2.post_id ) WHERE mt1.meta_key = 'goals-made' AND( mt2.meta_key = 'goals-against' AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS UNSIGNED) > CAST(mt2.meta_value AS UNSIGNED))")`.

Comment: Excellent! You should post this as another answer, for posterity.

Comment: Essentially: *1)* you treat `meta_table` as 2 separate tables, so you have to `INNER JOIN` 2 times. *2)* inside the `ON` clause use the table alias if you define it, not the table name. *3)* use `UNSIGNED` instead of `INT`. See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast)

Comment: Just edited my anser for posterity.

Comment: Nice. And Mister Melotte was never seen or heard from again lol ;)

Answer (score 2):

Hope I didn't understand the question wrong :)

```
$results = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'  => 'matches',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'goals-made',
            'value'   => (int) get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'goals-against',  true ),
            'type'    => 'INT',
            'compare' => ">",
        )
    ),
) );
if ( $results->have_posts() )
{
    while ( $results->have_posts() )
    {
        the_post();
        var_dump( $GLOBALS['post'] );
    }
}
```

As we don't know from where you're doing this query, simply replace `get_the_ID()` inside `get_post_meta()` with the retrieved ID of the posts you want to compare against.

Comment: mmm, the OP **don't** want compare posts agains *one* specific post, but want retrieve all posts that not only have both two meta fields, but also one meta value is > the other meta value, but both fields attached to post itself. I dont't know if it's more clear now...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand the question either, because the answer is obvious to me. I assume this is for one post, so you'd have 2 custom fields, foo and bar.

So in code...

```
$foo = get_field('foo');
$bar = get_field('bar');
if ($foo > $bar) {
    echo 'foo is greater than bar';
} else {
    echo 'bar is greater than foo';
}
```